# Using the output of a command as a set for tr

Tags: command-line, posix

For my systems programming course, I'm supposed to go through a piece of sample text and replace the most frequent word with another phrase. Unfortunately, I am only allowed to use the commands

```
tr
grep
egrep
sed
awk
uniq
wc
```

as well as piping. I have gotten so far as to find the most frequent word and wish to use it in SET1 for tr so that I can replace it with the other phrase. In order to do so I imagine that I have to filter out the line/word that is relevant with something like grep or sed. My question is then how I would pass that in as the first set for tr so that I could replace the phrase. I have no experience with awk.

Comment: "Only allowed to use ... `awk`...", well well well... `awk` is a swiss army knife in itself. You could easily implement the functionality of all the other tools with `awk` alone :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely don't want to use `tr` to do that, as `tr` only works on individual characters (or bytes):

```
$ echo abc | tr cab taxi
axt
```

I would recommend taking a look into `sed` and especially the `s///` (substitute) operator instead.

As for passing the output of a program to the command line of another, the keyword is [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution).

<sub>(I won't go into further detail since this was homework...)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Since this homework assignment is now more than two weeks old, I'll give my solution to it (replaces the most frequent whitespace-separated word with the string `FOO!`):

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/awk -f
>
> {
>     for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
>         if (NR == FNR) {
>             if (++c[$i] > c[m])
>                 m = $i
>         } else {
>             if ($i == m)
>             $i = "FOO!"
>         }
> }
>
>
> NR != FNR
> ```

This `awk` script should be invoked with the file mentioned twice on the command line:

```
$ ./script.awk file file
```

The only downside to this script is that whitespace on lines containing the most frequent word will be compressed into a single space.

---

Variation that fixes the above mentioned problem (or at least behaves better):

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/awk -f
>
> NR == FNR {
>     for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
>         if (++c[$i] > c[m])
>             m = $i
> }
>
>
> NR != FNR {
>     gsub(FS m FS, FS "FOO!" FS)
>     print
> }
> ```